# How do we replace a column in a tibble with another vector of identical length without changing the variable name?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large data frame that I coerced as a tibble to be able to use the `dplyr` package. I wanted to know if there was a way to "replace" a column in the tibble with the same variable in a different notation.

I have tried the `mutate()` function but I don't want to add a new column to the tibble, just replace a column with a vector of the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the name of your variable inside the mutate. For example, if you want to divide by 100:

```
mutate(var = var/100)
```

Comment: if that answered your question, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the answer is `mutate()`!

```
> library(dplyr)
> d <- tibble(x=1:3,y=2:4)
> d <- d %>% mutate(x=8:10) ## replace column x
> d
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     8     2
2     9     3
3    10     4
```